Superset warm-up cache ERROR 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing
When i use celery to warm up cache for superset it error.That is my config cache and celery in superet_config.py:
CACHE_CONFIG = {
    "CACHE_TYPE": "RedisCache",
    "CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT": 300,
    "CACHE_KEY_PREFIX": "superset_",
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
}

DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 60,  
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'data_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/2'
}

FILTER_STATE_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 300,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_filter_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/4'
}

EXPLORE_FORM_DATA_CACHE_CONFIG = {
    'CACHE_TYPE': 'RedisCache',
    'CACHE_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT': 300,
    'CACHE_KEY_PREFIX': 'superset_explore_',
    'CACHE_REDIS_URL': 'redis://localhost:6379/5'
}

class CeleryConfig:
    broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/1'
    imports = (
        "superset.sql_lab",
        "superset.tasks.scheduler",
        "superset.tasks.thumbnails",
        "superset.tasks.cache",
    )
    result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/6'
    worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
    task_acks_late = True
    beat_schedule = {
        "cache-warmup-hourly": {
        "task": "cache-warmup",
        "schedule": crontab(minute='*', hour='*'),  
        "kwargs": {"strategy_name": "dummy"}, 
        },
    }

CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig

it is error 405 Method Not Allowed. I did try 28706, but affter i getting error 400 bad request
superset:

celery:

.
I trying superset-4.1.0rc4 but it is still similar.
So what do i do? anyone help me?
